# Unwanted redirect to keycloak login page after succesfull login

Tags: angular, keycloak

I have a small angular application that is connected with a keycloak server for authentication ( I'm using keycloak-js version 7.0.1 ); I'm facing this strange behaviour: when I start my application I'm correctly redirect to the keycloak login page; I insert the correct credentials and then I'm redirect to my application home page ( until this point, everything as expected ). The problem is that, after 5-10 seconds, I'm redirect again to the keycloak login page. I can't understand if the problem is the server configuration or the js adapter. 
This is the code I have added to the angular app:

keycloak.service.ts

```
declare var Keycloak: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KeycloakService {

  constructor() { }

  private keycloakAuth: any;
  init(): Promise<any> {
  console.log("KEYCLOAKSERVICE:init");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.keycloakAuth = new Keycloak(environment.keycloakConfig);
    console.log(this.keycloakAuth);
    this.keycloakAuth.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' })
      .success(() => {
        console.log(this.keycloakAuth);
        resolve();
      })
      .error(() => {
        reject();
      });
    });
}
getToken(): string {
  console.log("getToken");
  return this.keycloakAuth.token;
}


logout(){
  console.log("logout");
  this.keycloakAuth.logout();
}

}
```

app.module.ts

```
export function kcFactory(keycloakService: KeycloakService) {
  console.log("kcFACTORY");
  return () => keycloakService.init();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomePageComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    ContainerListItemComponent,
    ContainerListComponent,
    TestComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    StorageServiceModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    KeycloakService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: kcFactory,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The keycloak server has Confidential access type, with fine-grained authorization enabled

Any suggestion?

Comment: Does your client app auto-redirect to KeyCloak login page if the user is not authenticated? If so, how is authentication currently determined? (i.e. is it persisted to localstorage, to cookies, etc) 

Could you include some of your code?

Comment: Hi Christian, I've added the Angular code in the original question; if the user is not authenticated the browser stay on the keycloak login page; the information about keycloak are saved in an external mysql db ( I didn't use H2 )